# Why can't I import a function from views into a model in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i have the following view function

```
def test():
    print 'test'
```

when i try to use this function in my model class and use an import:

```
from group.views import test
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/groups/models.py", line 14, in <module>
    from groups.views import test
  File "/groups/views.py", line 10, in <module>
    from groups.models import Group
ImportError: cannot import name Group
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular import issue. Your models file has a views import, then your views import has a model import. There are a number of ways to solve this, we'd have to see your models and views source.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is really old, but just in case it might help someone else, I wanted to share how I fixed this when I had this same problem.  As @professorDante has said it is a circular import issue, and so I was able to simply create another file, which I called `shared_functions.py` and move the function, `test()`, into that file.  Then I could import the function in to both of my files that previously had the circular import issue as:

```
from .shared_functions import test
```